# Adding values to char* var from txt file

Tags: c++, file-io

Example file:

```
[16bpp] Ponete el cinturon *-*
arfield
Nothing (cumpleanios):
Alkon^
~~|Tampon)
[16bpp] Chico Tonto.
Budin
16bpp] Leooooooooo!!!!!
Ev
16bpp] fedee
etamod
:) mAnKeAno
```

I want each name on a different array position...

I tried this code:

```
int c;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("bots.txt", "r");
if (file){
    char *buffer;
    char *jugadores = new char[1000];
    int p;
    int pos;
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF){
        if (c == '\n'){
            strcpy(jugadores[p], buffer);
            p++;
            buffer = "";
            pos = 0;
        } else {
            buffer[pos] = c;
            pos++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

But it doesn't even compile...

In php the right code would be something like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$names = explode("\n", $data);
```

Comment: a) So you want an array of strings, one string per line of file? b) But it doesn't even compile - well give us the error message. It's kind of important!

Comment: What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: Yes I want an array of strings. Exactly, one string per line. The error is becuase I'm not using the right var type that fit my needs so I think it wasn't necesary to show the error.

Comment: You are not initializing `p` or `pos` before using them, you are not allocating any memory for `buffer`, and `jugadores` is an array of characters instead of an array of character strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several flaws in it.  You need something more like this instead:

```
FILE *file = fopen("bots.txt", "r");
if (file)
{
    char** lines = new char*[1000];
    int maxlines = 1000;
    int numlines = 0;

    char *buffer = new char[1024];
    int maxbuf = 1024;
    int buflen = 0;

    char *line;

    int c;
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            if (numlines == maxlines)
            {
                char** tmplines = new char*[maxlines+1000];
                memcpy(tmplines, lines, sizeof(char*)*maxlines);
                delete[] lines;
                lines = tmplines;
                maxlines += 1000;
            }

            line = new char[buflen+1];
            memcpy(line, buffer, sizeof(char)*buflen);
            line[buflen] = 0;

            lines[numlines] = line
            numlines++;

            buflen = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if (buflen == maxbuf)
            {
                char* tmpbuf = new char[maxbuf+1024];
                memcpy(tmpbuf, buffer, sizeof(char)*maxbuf);
                delete[] buffer;
                buffer = tmpbuf;
                maxbuf += 1024;
            }

            buffer[buflen] = c;
            buflen++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    if (buflen > 0)
    {
        if (numlines == maxlines)
        {
            char** tmplines = new char*[maxlines+1000];
            memcpy(tmplines, lines, sizeof(char*)*maxlines);
            delete[] lines;
            lines = tmplines;
            maxlines += 1000;
        }

        line = new char[buflen+1];
        memcpy(line, buffer, sizeof(char)*buflen);
        line[buflen] = 0;

        lines[numlines] = line
        numlines++;
    }

    delete[] buffer;

    // use lines up to numlines elements as needed...
    for (int i = 0; i < numlines; i++)
        printf("%s\n", lines[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < numlines; ++i)
        delete[] lines[i];
    delete[] lines; 
}
```

With that said, since you are using C++, you should use C++ classes that will help manage everything for you.  Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <ostream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::ifstream file("bots.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
        lines.push_back(line);
    file.close();

    // use lines as needed...
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
        std::cout << lines[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: How are you showing the line exactly?  Please show that code.

Comment: for (int i=0; i < sizeof jugadores; i++){ printf("%s\n", jugadores[i]);}

Comment: In your original code, `sizeof(jugadores)` is always 4 or 8 (depending on 32bit or 64bit compiling) because it is a pointer to a dynamically allocated array and not a static array. You have to keep track of how many lines you put in the array. Also, `jugadores[i]` is a single `char`, not a `char*`, so using `%s` is wrong. In the C code I gave you, use `numlines` in the loop counter, and `lines[i]` will work correctly with `%s`. In the C++ code I gave you, use `lines.size()` in the loop counter, and `lines[i].c_str()` will work with `%s`, or use `std::cout` instead of `printf()`.