# Append user input to array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, append

I'm trying to write a program that asks for user inputs (one at a time, and continues until the user interrupts somehow) and stores them in an array. In python, I can easily append new inputs to the end of an existing list, but this doesn't work in C++. What's the easiest way to do this without involving vectors? I'm thinking of deleting the array each time and creating a new one that's larger, but this seems like a pain.

Comment: Why the restriction of not using vectors?

Comment: Honestly this is part of an assignment. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without straying too far from the stuff we covered in class. But if using vectors is the best way by far, go for it.

Comment: Hard to answer when we don't know what you have been studying in class so far. But it is hard to imagine being taught C++ without using C++ classes. But maybe the answer I posted to a similar question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851410/adding-values-to-char-var-from-txt-file/22851532#22851532

Comment: If you want to be a smart ass, you can use an std::list<>, which has an interface very similar to a vector, but it is not a vector. Hey, assignment still valid :P

Comment: Here's the precise wording of the assignment: "do not use elements from the Standard Template Library (STL) or other external libraries"

Comment: Ask the user how many entries he is going to input and allocate memory using new for the array

Comment: try using dynamic array and keep a count of how much elements are currently stored in array, next on new input you can store that value in count+1 index and so on, and if count==size create new array, copy elements from previous one and then delete it and you are done

Answer (score 0):

This is some code I wrote up to do this, it basically creates a new array and copies over data from the old array. Hopefully this can help you. To give you an example of its usage, there is a demonstation area that inputs data from stdin until the user types "END" and the prints it to stdout excluding the "END".

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

//Assuming you are storing strings
//Set this to the appropriate max length. The name of this may be misleading,
const int MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 128;                   //any other suggestions?
char** userInput;
int userInputUsed;
int userInputSize;

void append (char* text, int textLength) {
    //If we have used up all the space in the array
    if (userInputUsed >= userInputSize) {
        //How large you want the new array to be compared to
        //the original size (userInputSize)
        int newArraySize = 2*userInputSize;
        //Create the new array
        char** newUserInput = new char*[newArraySize];
        //We are only creating the new part of the array
        //Another way you could do this is to create the strings as you go
        for (int i = userInputUsed;i < newArraySize;i++) {
            newUserInput[i] = new char[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
        }
        //Copy everything over, I am setting our pointers to the old data
        for (int i = 0;i < userInputUsed;i++) {
            newUserInput[i] = userInput[i];
        }
        //Delete the old array
        delete[] userInput;
        //Set the new array to the old array
        userInput = newUserInput;
        //Update the size of our array;
        userInputSize = newArraySize;
    }
    //Copy the input to userInput
    memcpy(userInput[userInputUsed], text, textLength);
    userInputUsed++;
}

int main () {

    //Initialise userInput, initialise to whatever size you deem fit
    userInputSize = 1;
    userInput = new char*[userInputSize];
    for (int i = 0;i < userInputSize;i++) {
        userInput[i] = new char[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    }

    //Start of demonstration
    //Get input until the user types "END"
    for (bool running = true;running;) {
        char temp[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
        //Scans in until some whitespace, this may not work if
        //you want to scan in whole lines which end in '\n'
        //scanf("%s", temp);
        //or
        std::cin >> temp;
        //End if input is "END"
        if (strcmp(temp, "END") == 0) {
            running = false;
        } else {
            append(temp, strlen(temp));
        }
    }

    //Print out the user input, to see that it is inputed correctly
    for (int i = 0;i < userInputUsed;i++) {
        //printf("%s\n", userInput[i]);
        //or
        std::cout << userInput[i] << std::endl;
    }
    //End of demonstration

    //Cleanup our user input
    for (int i = 0;i < userInputSize;i++) {
        delete[] userInput[i];
    }
    delete[] userInput;

    //Stop the program from ending, you may not need this
    //while(true);

    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to comment or suggest improvements to this answer.